# How do you see the specific methods responsible for memory allocation in XCode Instruments?

Tags: xcode, memory, malloc, instruments, allocation

I've been asked to try and reduce memory usage in an app's code I have been given. The app runs fine in the simulator but on the device it is terminated or something, when debugging it enters a 'Paused' state and the app closes on the device.

When running instruments I discovered leaks, fixed them, however there is a large amount of allocation going on. Within a few seconds of launch the instruments allocation trace shows 1,021 KB for 'Malloc 16 Bytes'. This is essentially useless information as is, I need to see where the memory is being allocated but I can't seem to find anything useful. All i can get for a deeper inspection is that 'dyld', 'libsystem_c.dylib', 'libCGFreetype.A.dylib' etc are allocating a lot, but the responsible caller is never a recognizable method from the app source.

How can I see what methods are causing the most allocations here? I need to get this usage down! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Opening the extended detail view will show the call stack for memory allocations. Choose View > Extended Detail to open the extended detail view.

Switching to the call tree view will help you find where you are allocating memory in your code. Use the jump bar to switch to the call tree view.

Answer (score 0):

1MB is no big deal. You can't do much in terms of throwing up a full view without using 1MB.

There's a good video from WWDC 2010 (http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) that covers using instruments to analyze memory use. Title is Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments. There may be an updated video from 2011.

Comment: Actually the total allocation for memory is 38MB right after launch. I still can't get an allocation backtrace but I'm watching the video right now. My test hardware is iPad 1, which seems like a pretty finiky device for memory usage, a lot of apps seem to have problems being terminated by the OS for mem problems. Look at Infinity Blade II :)

Comment: Ah. You weren't saying the 1M was a problem, but that it was useless information. I understand. 38M is a bit scary if there's no known good reason for it. I think watching all the videos you can find with respect to Instruments is a good approach. Instruments is very powerful but can be a little hard to pick up. The videos can help a lot.

Comment: The reason is a UIScrollView with approx 1000 UIImages in it. I am investigating the best way to load the images dynamically based on the visible area of the UIScrollView, and unload the non-visible ones, to reduce the massive memory load.

Comment: UIScrollView with non-lazy loaded images is never a good idea.