# Source of CFData (store) allocation at app start

Tags: macos, cocoa, instruments, cfdata

At app start, my Cocoa app instantly creates two `CFData` objects. One of size 34 MB and another of size 57 MB. I cannot seem to figure out what these objects are or where they are coming from within Instruments.

[image: Instruments]

Both are allocated before `applicationWillFinishLaunching` completes.

I have tried clearing `NSURLCache` as well as clearing my `Kingfisher` image cache and am open to other ideas for cleaning out this data. **How can I find the source of these allocations?**

Comment: I think Instruments can tell you the stack trace of an allocation?

Comment: @tbodt I imagine so, but not sure which subtool or pathway to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412607/how-do-you-see-the-specific-methods-responsible-for-memory-allocation-in-xcode-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be caused by NSUserDefaults. Earlier in development, I had saved some large files there, which were never deleted.

Here is what the **Instruments call tree** revealed.

[image: Stack Trace]

From there I tried using

```
NSUserDefaults.resetStandardUserDefaults()
```

But that did nothing. Nor did cleaning my project or deleting the Derived Data folder manually.

Following this answer brought my CFData allocation to zero:
[Clearing NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545091/clearing-nsuserdefaults)